# Join vides of different formats

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codec

I have a collection of videos that have been recorded and encoded with various different devices and codecs. I try to make one movie out of them. I thought it's a good idea to bring them all to the same format, so I run the following command on all videos

```
ffmpeg -i "${input}" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac "${output}"
```

Then, after putting the filenames into a list, I try the concat demuxer

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy "${output}"
```

(I also tried reencoding again with the same codecs as above, but the result is the same.)

But the process gives many errors [1], and the output video jumps back and forth. Before hunting down the cause of all errors, is there a better way to join many different videos of different sources, different age, different codecs, different everything?

[1] Errors are numerous, e.g.:

```
[mp4 @ 0x5588e448ec80] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 1192126, current: 1160221; changing to 1192127. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[h264 @ 0x5588e44d0b80] Reference 6 >= 4
[h264 @ 0x5588e44d0b80] error while decoding MB 53 1, bytestream 6271
```

Comment: Are they all the same resolution, colour space, and framerate? They could complicate things. You may need to unify those things with resizing and framerate conversion before you re-encode. Software like Adobe Premiere comes to mind.

Comment: @zwei7 Not necessarily same resolution and such. Would this be possible with ffmpeg as well? I would like to automate the process.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
WID=1280
HEI=720
# WID="$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=width -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$f")"
# HEI="$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=height -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$f")"
INP=()
FCT=-1
PAD=""
FIL=""
for f in *.mp4; do
  echo $f
  INP+=("-i")
  INP+=("$f")
  ((FCT+=1))
  s="[${FCT}v0]"
  PAD+="[${FCT}:v:0]pad=${WID}:${HEI}:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2${s};"
  FIL+="${s}[${FCT}:a:0]"
done
((FCT+=1))
ffmpeg -hide_banner "${INP[@]}" -filter_complex "${PAD}${FIL}concat=n=${FCT}:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map [v] -map [a] -c:v h264_nvenc -cq 23 -c:a aac -y output.mkv
```

it doesn't work fine, need to do many improvements. Main job is to pad black spaces to get same resolution on all videos.

How it works:

1. find maximal width and height of videos, replace vars WID=1280 and HEI=720 with your resolution values
2. replace *.mp4 with your extensions or your expression
3. change codecs
4. run script in dir with video, script will generate string, something like this:

ffmpeg -i "input 1.mp4" -i "input 2.mp4" -filter_complex [0:v:0]pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[0v0];[1:v:0]pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[1v0];[0v0][0:a:0][1v0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map [v] -map [a] -c:v h264_nvenc -cq 23 -c:a aac -y output.mkv

and run it. Each part of filter sequence with pad:

```
[0:v:0]pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[0v0];
```

will pad blank spaces around video for resolution's alignment.

Comment: I think this is a very good answer, but it needs a bit of explanation.

Comment: Maybe use a GUI?